# youcompleteme config golang to auto import package when first use package

Tags: go, vim, vi, vim-plugin, youcompleteme

When using VIM with Youcompleteme to write the go language, when the current file first references a package file, how to configure ycm_extra.conf so that the first time can also automatically fill and import the corresponding header